# E mail id storing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

how we can store the e mail id into a database? i mean which datatype is used for storing e mail id's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The natural choice would be a VARCHAR or the equivalent in your DBMS. There really isn't any reason to store an email address as anything other than a text string.

Comment: there is one variable left - number of characters :)

Answer (score 0):

Type VARCHAR. I would also suggest that you encrypt the email addresses, using an algorithm and a secret salt key. Emails are sensitive information and is a good idea to store them encrypted so in case of data theft your clients wont find themselves on spam lists.